# Why am i unable to connect node in shading?

Tags: node-editor, shaders

[image]

I want to connect colour to surface, but i am neither able to select colour nor surface as shown in

Comment: You can't connect color to surface .You will need a background node in between click shift +A and search for it. To put it simply the background node converts your HDRi to proper spherical manner and makes it emmit light to reflect on the objects in the scene. Also notice that the color output is yellow and the surface input is green..

Comment: Can't say for sure why you are not able to select the nodes. It might be a bug

Comment: Are you really trying to setup a background shader?

Comment: Ron Jensen. Yes. But i am unable to select any node such as colour surface or volume. If I click on it nothing happens. Is there any prerequisite for clicking on that. @nxdhin2005, if it was  a bug then all people who downloaded 2.8.3 must have this problem?.

Comment: Can't say for sure... It depends on your hardware too